# matplotlib, increase scatter size while keep legend size small

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to increase the size of the "bubbles" inside a scatter plot. However when I call legend on the data, the size of the "bubbles" in the legend is equally large. Does anyone know a way to make the legend "bubbles" small while keeping the scatter "bubbles" large?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `plt.legend(markerscale=k)`, where `k` is the scaling factor for the legend, relative to the plot's marker size. Details are in the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html) on legends where you can see all of the possible arguments.